# Flat collection to One to Many collection

Tags: c#, linq

I need to take a list of objects created as a result of a query with joins etc and produce an object hierarchy of one to many.  How would I do this with Linq?

```
class Source
{
  int Id,
  string Name,
  ....  
  int MemberId,
  string MemberName,
  ....
}

class Target
{
  int Id,
  string Name,
  ....
  ICollection<Member> Members
}

class Member
{
  int Id,
  string Name,
  ....
}
```

Example Data

```
List = 
{
  new Source {Id = 1, Name = "Test1", ... MemberId = 1, MemberName = "John", ...},
  new Source {Id = 2, Name = "Test2", ... MemberId = 2, MemberName = "Max", ...},
  new Source {Id = 2, Name = "Test2", ... MemberId = 4, MemberName = "Ruby", ...}
}
```

Desired outcome

```
List = 
{
  new Target {Id = 1, Name = "Test1", ... 
              Members = new List { new Member {Id = 1, Name = "John", ...}}
             },
  new Target {Id = 2, Name = "Test2", ... 
              Members = new List { new Member {Id = 2, Name = "Max", ...},
                                   new Member {Id = 4, Name = "Ruby", ...}}
             }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `Enumerable.GroupBy`, you have to group by an anonymous type:

```
var result = List
    .GroupBy(s => new { s.Id, s.Name })
    .Select(xGrp => new Target
    {
        Id = xGrp.Key.Id,
        Name = xGrp.Key.Name,
        Members = xGrp
            .Select(s => new Member 
            { 
                Id = s.MemberId, 
                Name = s.MemberName
            })
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```